# Get a number nth bit value in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

How can I get nth bit value in oracle database?
I am currently using this query:

```
WITH a AS
     (SELECT 7 val
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT CASE BITAND (a.val, POWER (2, n-1))
          WHEN 0
             THEN 0
          ELSE 1
       END nth_bit
  FROM a
```

Comment: nth bit value of what?

Comment: of a number. 7 for here

Comment: That works. What are you looking for?

Comment: simpler query! my original query is too big and complex. I need reduce its size for preventing confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest expression you can get is:

```
least(bitand(a, power(2, n-1)), 1)
```

where you want to find the `n`th bit of `a`.

The shortest query with this expression is:

```
select least(bitand(a, power(2, n-1)), 1) from dual;
```

From what I've read the above expression also works in PL/SQL, eg:

```
l_bit_n := least(bitand(a, power(2, n-1)), 1);
```

Comment: If this is for PL/SQL -- or if the cost of context switches between SQL and PL/SQL aren't important (ie you aren't querying millions of rows), then I would put the expression into its own PL/SQL function.

Answer (score -1):

```
with a
as
(select 8 as value,4 as bit_number  from dual)
SELECT CASE WHEN BITAND (a.value, POWER (2, a.bit-1))=POWER (2, a.bit -1)
            THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END nth_bit
FROM a
```

Comment: It is same as my query!

Comment: How is this different from the query presented by the OP?